# Mounting shares from Synology NAS persistent on boot up

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, nfs, nas

**Mounting shares from Synology NAS persistent on boot up**

I'm using Ubuntu 20.4 with a Synology NAS that is accessible easily from Windows and Mac

I can mount the shares using the following command in terminal:

```
sudo mount -o uid=linuxusername,username=shareuser,pass=sharepass //192.168.1.2/music /home/profile/Music/musicone
```

However, that's labourious since I have several sharepoints to mount, therefore I want to mount using `fstab` for persistent mount, so I made this entry:

```
//192.168.42.2/music /home/profile/Music/musicone cifs uid=linuxuser,username=sharepointuser,pass=sharepointpass 0 0
```

I had a lot of problems making that `fstab` file work, but finally I got it tweaked. I'm leaving this here in case I can help others with the same mounting issue. That is the functioning syntax. I did try using gid instead of uid, but that did not work, so this only works for one user, I think. (I only have one user, and the mounts are in that home directory)

However ...
I'd prefer to use a file for credentials, so I made a file called `.smbcredentials`, substituting `credentials=filepath` for the username and password.

This is not working. The sharepoint appears, but opening as user yields an error that it can only be mounted as root, and opening as root says

```
mount:/home/profile/Documents/nas: you may need a file type detail like /sbin/mount.(filetype) helper program
```

but I don't know where to place that in the syntax. There's no `mount.smb` option in sbin, but there is `mount.nfs` which could work, because my NAS has NFS turned on. But it doesn't, with the first error saying the share is not in host:dir format. Adding a colon after the IP of the server did not help and that didn't even get to the authentication part.

I did try putting `/sbin/mount.nfs` in a few places in the syntax, leaving in the nfs reference (where cifs goes) but nothing would make the share available.

Mounting with a group id (`gid=1000`) would be better, (and I'd put the mountpoints in `/mnt/`) but that's not working, so if I added a user, I'd be in trouble there.

Here's two of the dozens of web pages I looked at, these yielded the most, but obviously not complete, results.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently
https://deathofagremmie.com/2012/05/01/mounting-a-synology-diskstation-on-ubuntu-12.04/#disqus_thread

Comment: subsituting 'nfs' for 'cifs' in the mount syntax does not successfully mount the sharepoints. in user, I can see the shares, but I cannot open them. In user mode I get  "only permitted as root" and in root mode I get "mount.nfs: share not in host:dir format" 
Adding a colon after the server's IP did not resolve this problem. that was one suggestion I had tried, I'd be very happy if you could provide a syntax for sharing.
adding the colon gave the error "failed to resolve server, name or service unknown.

Comment: Do you have a `mount.cifs` in `/sbin`?

Comment: no, I don't have that. I do have mount.nfs.
mounting cifs works fine, except I can't put the credentials in a file and read them.

Comment: I reconfigured the Synology, adding an NFS permisson on one of the shares. I confgured mapping root to admin, and configured a matching user for my linux "profile" account, with read-write permissions on the nfs share. I can easily browse to the folder through the network, but have been unsuccessful in mounting it with nfs profile@Ubuntu-pc:~$ 
    sudo mount 192.168.42.2:/volume2/MusicTwo /home/profile/Music/nfstest 
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.42.2:/volume2/MusicTwo

Comment: I keep getting "access denied by server" after trying several tweaks to the NFS permissions on the server and in the nfs options. For me, NFS is a non-starter for mounting it. I can browse to it, since I have a user account on the Synology now, but I can't mount it. Not by command line, nor in the fstab. The prohibits access to the share from several programs as they won't access it unless it's locally mounted.

Comment: Try enabling `sftp` in Synology NAS. Then either use [`sshfs`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS) in `/etc/fstab` to mount. Alternately use something like `sftp://peter@synology.local/NetBackup/Computer_to_be_backedup/peter` as the storage location in DejaDup, the default backup app in Ubuntu.

Comment: If you think the answer below is correct then click on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will mark the problem as solved and help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a `mount.cifs` in `/sbin`?  If not, try and install `smbclient`

```
sudo apt-get install smbclient
```

I used to do so but now I use `automount`.  That solution has the advantage of automatically mounting your shares as soon as your NAS becomes available.

Edit:
Re-installing `cifs-utils`, it worked (`sudo apt install cifs-utils`)

Comment: I ran that install, but neither mount.cifs or mount.smb is not in /sbin

Comment: Are the `cifs-utils`also installed? (`sudo apt install cifs-utils`)

Comment: I did install smbclient, but it did not improve anything

Comment: yes, cifs-utils were install some time ago

Comment: @PeterAddison Very strange because mount.cifs  belongs to cifs-utils (https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mount.cifs).  Maybe be a reinstall could solve the problem.

Comment: Kowabunga. when I re-installed the cifs-utils it worked with the credentials installed in the file .smbcredentians in my home directory.

Comment: //192.168.42.2/fileshare /home/profile/Documents/nasfiles cifs uid=profile,credentials=/home/profile/.smbcredentials 0 0

Comment: how do I post that so it comes in the grey background?

Comment: @PeterAddison: just use the backtick "`" before and after the text.  Or use the <kbd>{}</kbd> button.

Comment: @PeterAddison Also, if the answer solved the problem, mark it as 'accepted', so that further users can spot it easily.